# Usar valor de variável ainda não declarada. Referência Circular no c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Sei que a pergunta parece absurda mas um cliente meu me passou uma planilha do excel que possui uma variável que é usada antes de ter seu calculo definido. No excel isso chama Referência Circular.

Preciso fazer isso no meu código.

Segue a parte onde preciso disso:

```
decimal valorFaturamentoPrevistoObra = ((subtotalGrupo1 + subtotalGrupo2) + valorDespesasEspecificas) * (1 + bdi);

decimal taxaRateioAdmCentral = (valorAdmCentralPeriodo * (valorFaturamentoPrevistoObra / (valorFaturamentoPeriodo + valorFaturamentoPrevistoObra)) / (subtotalGrupo1 + subtotalGrupo2)) * 100;

Taxa taxa = new Taxa();
var listaTaxas = taxa.ListaTaxaOrcamento(orcamento_id);

bdi = CalculaBDI(orcamento_id, listaTaxas, valorDespesasEspecificas, taxaRateioAdmCentral);
```

Reparem que preciso da variável "bdi" na primeira linha mas que o calculo dela só é feito mais pra baixo. E que para fazer o calculo dela preciso do valor da primeira linha.

Alguem tem alguma ideia de como resolver isso? Pode ser qualquer solução.

Referência Circular no c#

Comment: Creio que você terá que realizar um processo iterativo. Atribua um valor inicial para bdi e execute o cálculo várias vezes, utilizando o valor obtido em cada etapa para o bdi como entrada para a próxima iteração, até você atingir o erro desejado ou um número de iterações pré-definidas.

Comment: PS: o método iterativo é como o Excel resolve referências circulares: https://excelmaniacos.com/2016/12/19/dicas-quando-a-referencia-circular-e-desejada/

Comment: Acredito não ser o caso de referência circular. A exemplo do excel, passando para o C#, uma referencia circular seria algo como: `x = x +1;` ou seja: A variável é utilizada no próprio cálculo dela, e não isso de "uma variável ser usada antes de ter um valor definido". Acredito que o problema aí seja de lógica, talvez se explicar melhor o cálculo ou até mesmo mostrar a planilha com a formula dela, possamos ajudar

Comment: talvez ajude: http://construcaomercado17.pini.com.br/negocios-incorporacao-construcao/95/especial-obras-publicas-como-calcular-o-bdi-281833-1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Trata-se de um típico problema de programação linear e existem vários algoritmos para solucioná-lo. Você poderia utilizar, por exemplo, um algoritmo Simplex de maximização.

Muitas pessoas preferem usar o Excel para resolver esse tipo de problema porque ele já vem com ferramentas, como a [Teste de Hipóteses](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Introdu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ao-teste-de-hip%C3%B3teses-8b832128-bae9-434a-a124-625755e97c07?CorrelationId=ba598a7a-a33d-4c92-a7c8-323b6d24f4b2&ui=pt-BR&rs=pt-BR&ad=BR&ocmsassetID=HA010342628) e [Solver](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Definir-e-resolver-um-problema-usando-o-Solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040?CorrelationId=4f150c66-16a5-4caa-ae13-e6748bf15726&ui=pt-BR&rs=pt-BR&ad=BR&ocmsassetID=HP010342416), que implementam alguns algoritmos de programação linear.

Particularmente, eu considero complexa a implementação desses algorítimos. Depois das minhas aulas de Pesquisa Operacional (e isso já faz muito tempo!), eu nunca mais precisei implementar um deles. Das poucas vezes que me deparei com um problema assim, eu usei o Excel mesmo.

**Solução 1**

Para uma solução robusta e eficiente, eu sugiro que você implemente em seu sistema um [algoritmo de programação linear](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/prog-lin/). Você encontra uma implementação do método Simplex de maximização em [Simplex maximization algorithm in C#](https://gist.github.com/trevordixon/9702052).

**Solução 2**

Para uma solução bem mais simples, você pode montar um loop de testes de hipóteses até encontrar o valor mais adequado.

Considerando que você deseja encontrar o valor de `dbi` que resulte no maior valor possível para `valorFaturamentoPrevistoObra`, o algorítimo abaixo faz um loop para testar hipóteses do valor de faturamento até encontrar o valor maximizado (a explicação detalhada está nos comentários).

```
Taxa taxa = new Taxa();
var listaTaxas = taxa.ListaTaxaOrcamento(orcamento_id);

//Crie uma varíavel para determinar o menor valor possível do faturamento
decimal faturamentoMinimo = (subtotalGrupo1 + subtotalGrupo2 + valorDespesasEspecificas);

//Crie uma variável para testar hipóteses de valor do faturamento
//Como se quer um valor maximizado, inicie o valor da hipoótese com um valor bem alto
//Estou sugerindo aqui que seja 3 vezes o faturamento mínimo mas pode ser maior ou menor
//Lembrando que, quanto maior, mais lenta será a execução
decimal hipoteseFaturamento = 3 * faturamentoMinimo;

//Faça um loop para testar o valor da hipótese até o limite mínmo
while (hipoteseFaturamento > faturamentoMinimo)
{
    //calcule a taxa de rateio com base no valor da hipótese
    taxaRateioAdmCentral = (valorAdmCentralPeriodo * (hipoteseFaturamento / (valorFaturamentoPeriodo + hipoteseFaturamento)) / (subtotalGrupo1 + subtotalGrupo2)) * 100;            

    //Calcule o bdi
    bdi = CalculaBDI(orcamento_id, listaTaxas, valorDespesasEspecificas, taxaRateioAdmCentral);

    //Calcule o faturamento previsto                
    valorFaturamentoPrevistoObra = ((subtotalGrupo1 + subtotalGrupo2) + valorDespesasEspecificas) * (1 + bdi);

    //Verifique se o faturamento previsto é igual à hipótese, 
    //se for igual, você encontrou o bdi desejado
    //se não for, diminua o valor da hipótese e calcule novamente               
    if (hipoteseFaturamento == valorFaturamentoPrevistoObra)
        break;
    else
        hipoteseFaturamento -= 1;                       
}
```